# Solving for side lengths of a triangle given specific conditions.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

For a given constant $b > 10,$ there are two possible triangles $ABC$ satisfying $AB = 10,$ $AC = b,$ and $\sin B = \frac{3}{5}.$ Find the positive difference between the lengths of side $\overline{BC}$ in these two triangles.

I'm not sure how to set up a system of equations to solve for the side lengths of BC in both triangles. Can I solve this in another way other than using algebra? How do I incorporate trig functions in this problem?

This question is from a mock contest made specifically for a contest math class I am taking, I do not have a public link to cite it with.

Comment: Please cite the source of this contest question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Apply the sine rule

\begin{align}
BC & = \frac{\sin A}{\sin B}b 
= \frac{\sin(B +C)}{\sin B}b = 
b(\cos C+ \cot B\sin C)\tag 1
\end{align}
where $\cot B= \pm \frac43$ from $\sin B=\frac35$ and

$$\sin C= \frac{10}b \sin B=\frac6b, \>\>\>\>\>
\cos C= \frac1b \sqrt{b^2-36} $$

Substitute above into (1) to get $BC_{1,2} = \sqrt{b^2-36} \pm 8$, which yields the difference 
$$BC_1-BC_2 = 16$$

Comment: I get a different answer that depends on $b$, but in my diagram, $B,C_1,c_2$ are collinear.  I think the problem is ambiguous.  Please look at my solution and tell me what you think.

Comment: @saulspatz - you may have missed the condition $b>10$

Comment: That's the second time today I've overlooked a simple condition in the question.  Thanks.